# Switch - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement

I´ve this issue in this test case program:

```
package testecase;

public class TesteCase {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        switch (args [0] .charAt (0)) {
        case 'A':System.out.println("Vogal A ");
        break;

        case 'E':System.out.println("Vogal E ");
        break;

        default:System.out.println("Não é vogal ");

        }
    }
}
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: Do you are passing args when you are running the code?

Comment: check args.lenght >0

Comment: just pass an arg to your program. `java TestCase Abc` for example to enter in the first case

Comment: General hint: You should add a check if arguments have been actually passed. *Never "trust" user input!* A common practice is to output a ["usage" - Message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message) and exit.

Comment: If you running this from within an IDE like Eclipse you need to add arguments to your run configuration. Or if you are running it from a commandline then you do `java TestCase yourstring`.

Answer (score 1):

The exception tells you that **at runtime** your `args` array doesn't have **any** entries.

You change that by invoking the JVM like

```
java TestCase A B C
```

In other words: that array **holds** the parameters that you give to the JVM when starting it. No parameters on the command line ... ends up in an empty array.

Or giving another view: your code contains **two** assumptions about the incoming data:

1. Using `args [0]` **requires** that the array has at least **one** entry
2. Using `....charAt(0)` **requires** that this first entry as at least **one** character

And guess what: that isn't necessarily true!

You learned your first, very valuable lesson about programming: do not expect that "reality" at runtime just matches your assumptions how it *should* look like.

Meaning: when data is coming in from the outside, the first step is to **validate** that it meets your expectations. Like:

```
if (args.length > 0) {
 ... process input
} else {
 tell user: no input
```

Similar for that String processing you intend to do!

Comment: Thanks bro! helps a lot =D

Comment: You are very welcome. Feel free to accept at any time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are sending an argument to your program when running it: `java TesteCase A`

Also, in general, you should not trust the user input so I'd advise you to check the lenght of args first. Once you know that it's not empty, you can try to read it.